# R Doesn't Execute Command Line

Tags: r, command-line, exe

I am trying to execute command line via R code (entire script at end of post)

```
system('"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\convert.exe" -delay 20 -loop 0 *.png julia.gif')
```

Of course, I downloaded and installed [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) and verified `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16` exists on my machine

The desired result is to create below animation from the output (35 .png files, copies on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/Julia/tree/master/output)).

The syntax looks correct, what am I overlooking?

[image]

**R code (inspired by [Fronkonstin Blog](https://fronkonstin.com/2016/05/17/playing-with-julia-set/))**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
setwd("C:/JuliaSet")
dir.create("output")
setwd("output")
f = function(z,c) exp(z^3)+c
# Grid of complex
z0 <- outer(seq(-2, 2, length.out = 1200),1i*seq(-2, 2, length.out = 1200),'+') %>% c()
opt <-  theme(legend.position="none",
              panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"),
              plot.margin=grid::unit(c(1,1,0,0), "mm"),
              panel.grid=element_blank(),
              axis.ticks=element_blank(),
              axis.title=element_blank(),
              axis.text=element_blank())
for (i in 1:35)
{
  z=z0
  # i iterations of f(z)
  for (k in 1:i) {
    z <- f(z, c=-0.621) 
    df=data.frame(x=Re(z0),
    y=Im(z0),
    z=as.vector(exp(-Mod(z)))) %>% na.omit() 
 }
  p=ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=z)) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours=brewer.pal(8, "Paired")) + opt
  ggsave(plot=p, file=paste0("plot", stringr::str_pad(i, 4, pad = "0"),".png"), width = 1.2, height = 1.2)
}
# Place the exact path where ImageMagick is installed
system('"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\convert.exe" -delay 20 -loop 0 *.png julia.gif')
# cleaning up
#file.remove(list.files(pattern=".png"))
```

Comment: Strange. Do you get an error message? Which one? I would try to replace `"C:\\Program Files\\..."` with the short path name `C:\\PROGRA~1\\...` (and remove the double quotes).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent No error message. Nothing happens. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: The author of your link uses such a path, with the double quotes. So it should work. Stupid question, but you're sure there's no file `julia.gif` in your current directory ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Correct, no `julia.gif`. However I looked at internally within `ImageMagick` and saw there is no `convert.exe`, rather there is `magick.exe`. Plus, I had to change `*.png` to `output/*.png`. Hence the correct line is `system('C:\\PROGRA~1\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\magick.exe -delay 20 -loop 0 output/*.png julia.gif')` So it is the `PROGRA~1` that works rather than `Program Files`. Thank you :-)

Comment: Yes, `convert.exe` is in the old versions of ImageMagick. But that's weird if you didn't get an error message. Well, this works now...

Comment: It seems like you've got things working, but you might want to look into the `magick` package instead of calling the external program.  You should be able to write a program that doesn't depend on where you installed ImageMagick.

Comment: @user2554330 That's a great idea!